# Transform array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know its a dumb question but I'm kinda stuck.

I have an array like this:

```
var arr = [[2, 5], [5,1], [6,7], [3,1]];
```

And I need to transform like this:

```
arr = [21, 41, 55, 25] //arr[0][0]*8 + arr[0][1]
```

Can someone explain how to achieve this?
for loop, .map()?

http://jsbin.com/wegohutemo/edit?js

Comment: How your output should look like ?

Comment: Look at lodash or underscore

Comment: @Engineer Or, you know... *loops*. Why is a whole library required for something that a single loop can do?

Comment: @deceze I said take a look, not jump in with both feet. The OP may have other tasks that could benefit and it helps to be aware of these things.

Comment: @Engineer OK... also look at AngularJS and MongoDB while you're at it!? And cream cheese! You can never have enough cream cheese! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `map` function to transform , see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/fpoa5vkv/)

```
arr = arr.map( function(value){

  return value[0]*8 + value[1]; //picks up one item at a time and apply your algorithm.

} )
```

Comment: it will be really great if you can add some `explanation` :)

Comment: First element should be 21

Comment: @RayonDabre yes, it worked without that on console :) ...updated code

Comment: @Hiero it does, check the demo in post

Comment: @RayonDabre I know which is why I have assigned the output to arr itself

Answer (score 2):

A bit different, but i treat the arrays as  octal numbers.

```js
var arr = [[2, 5], [5, 1], [6, 7], [3, 1]],
    result = arr.map(function (a) {
        return parseInt(a.join(''), 8);
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```